# Ocular similarities in Impact crater

Tags: meteorite, astrobiology, impact-craters

I know how crazy this will sound so let me ease into the craziness.

I recently read a paper on the Chicxulub crater and one line caught my attention detailing a hydrothermal vent system that resulted from the impact and “lived”
for tens of thousands of years-.  I then thought about the uniformity of impact craters both in structures and material compositions.l looked at some complex impact craters on mars and some had  internal structures which looked like they were arranged similar to a spectrophotometer used to split light into wavelengths and then thought generally how impact craters look like eyes and wondered if it was all more than metaphorical.

Here’s my thought process: at a basic level an eye would need a material to convert light into an electrical signal (photoelectric), a material to carry the signal (conductive) and then something to process the signal (some type of processor/brain).

Impact craters are usually rich in magnetite (photoelectric), have shock quartz veins (conductive- while the mechanism is a little complex) and this is the weakest part of the evidence but quartz can be also used to store and process info and shocked quartz has organized structure (I forget the name) that kinda seem like they could be binary.

Is there any other evidence that impact craters may be part of some type of sensor/life? Maybe one that uses geothermal heat as its energy source. I realize it’s far fetched but some of the crazy complexity and organization of Martian impact craters I’ve seen makes me curious if there isn’t more intent in their formation- maybe coded in electromagnetism or something.

And I’m not suggesting our understanding of the mechanisms behind impact crater formation is wrong, just incomplete and that there may be additional mechanism directing their formation.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, hydrothermal vents lasting for "thousands of years" is a very small period of time in geological time scales.

As to your hypothesis concerning shocked quartz & magnetite in impact craters somehow forming an optical sensing & processing system, until someone can provide evidence of such a possibility the answer would be, **exceedingly unlikely**.